# Executing MSBuild ExtensionPack tasks inside visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I have created a .target file to be imported into .csproj files. This target file imports MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks. When run from the commandline the ExtensionPack task gets executed fine, but if I run the build from inside visual studio the target still runs but it skips the extension task.

Here is the target file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <TPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Contrib\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(TPath)"/>


  <Target Name="FindWSFiles">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder TaskAction="FindFilesAndDirectories" Path="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" SearchPattern="*WS*">
      <Output ItemName="AllFoundItems" TaskParameter="FoundItems"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder>
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="===== Found Files and Directories =====" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="AllFoundItems:%0d%0a@(AllFoundItems,'%0d%0a')"/>
  </Target>  

  <Target Name="GenerateWSBin" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="FindWSFiles">
    <Message Text="GenerateWSBin" Importance="high" />  
  </Target>

  <Target Name="GenerateWSHooks" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="FindWSFiles">
    <Message Text="GenerateWSHooks" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

How can I get the MSBuild.ExtensionPack task to execute inside of visual studio?

Comment: Well this is weird. MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsVersion works perfectly fine inside Visual Studio. What is the difference between TfsVersion and FindUnder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this was a silly mistake on my part. I forgot to include `Importance="high"` inside `<Message Text="AllFoundItems:%0d%0a@(AllFoundItems,'%0d%0a')" />` This caused the output to be suppressed inside visual studio.

Comment: Accept the answer, so that it completes the question :)

Comment: I have to wait til tomorrow to answer my own question.